# Using data attribute in css3 color

Tags: css

I am trying to color a progress bar depending on the value.

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, attr(value) ,0,1);
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    border-radius:3px;

    /* Let's animate this */
    animation: animate-stripes 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Looks like attr(value) doesn't appear to work - is there a way to inject value in there? Using chrome

Comment: The dream of many, but at the moment, `attr()` only works in `content` properties - see [the second paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

Comment: Furthermore, ::-webkit-progress-value is not an official standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-value

Answer (score 0):

If you use pseudo element before to display your progress?
Maybe this could work?

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {

    &:before{
        content: [attr-data];
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(0, attr(value) ,0,1);
        background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
        border-radius:3px;

        /* Let's animate this */
        animation: animate-stripes 5s linear infinite;    
    } 

}
```